# get the number of documents before and after Firestore trigger - Cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the number of documents in a collection before and after a document has been added using `cloud functions`, the code in nodeJs I wrote is this:

```
exports.onShowcaseCreated = functions.firestore
.document("Show/{document}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const showcaseDict = snapshot.data();
  const uid = showcaseDict.uid;
  return db.collection("Showcases").where("uid", "==", uid).get()
      .then((showsnap) => {
          const numberOfShowcaseBefore = showsnap.size.before;
          const numberOfShowcaseAfter = showsnap.size.after;
          console.log( numberOfShowcaseBefore, numberOfShowcaseAfter);
          if ( numberOfShowcaseBefore == 0 && numberOfShowcaseAfter == 1 ) {
            return db.collection("Users").doc(uid).update({
              timestamp: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
            });
        });
      });
});
```

but the console logs are `undefined undefined` it seems like this is not the right approach for taking the number of documents before and after a document has beed added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `before` and `after` properties are only defined on the argument that is passed to `onCreate`. You *call* that `snapshot` in your code, but it's actually a `Change` object as defined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change).

Reading data from the database gives you a `QuerySnapshot` object as defined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). As you can see, that `size` on that `QuerySnapshot` is just a number and does not have `before` or `after` properties.

So there's no way to determine the size before the event triggered with your approach. Any query you run in the code, runs after the event was triggered so will give you the size at that moment.

---

To implement this use-case I'd recommend storing a count of the number of relevant documents in the database itself, and then triggering a Cloud Function when *that* document changes. Inside the Cloud Function code you can then read the previous and new value of the size from the `change` document that is passed in.

Comment: great answer, as always I'm a bit disappointed with the lack of features firebase offers